# Laptop charger replacement

Tags: laptop, charger

Is it safe to use these chargers to replace my lost laptop charger?

Original charger: 19V, 4.74A

- Replacement 1: 19V, 4.5A
- Replacement 2: 20V, 4.5A

Comment: The first one should do nicely. I use a similar one for two years now.

Comment: @rook - ok thanks. i was thinking the power might not be enough if i was using the first one.

Comment: It is always better to go a little over on the voltage and amperage than it is to go under. It will be safe enough, but you might kill your battery sooner.

Comment: @MaQleod - thanks. I have no choice but to use the charger anyways so might as well sacrifice battery life.

Answer (score 3):

A replacement must be the same voltage. Too little, and the battery won't charge. Too much, and you'll fry something.

The amperage should be the same or higher. If it's too much lower, it either won't work, or the adapter will overheat making the attempt to power the laptop. If it's higher, the laptop simply won't use the extra available power.

Answer (score 1):

Either charger should work fine.  The only difference is it will take very slightly longer to charge the battery than with your original charger.  There's no adverse affect on battery life from the lower amperage.  IF anything it might last just a bit longer since the heat generated (and dissipated inside the battery compartment) will be slightly less.  But we're talking a very small amount here - less than 1% I would think.